# Eclipse project wont work after export?

Tags: java, eclipse, export

This is my first game ever making, so I am pretty new to this and I am sorry if I missed something obvious.

My program works inside of eclipse, but for whatever reason it wont work outside as after export. I export by right-clicking on my project folder, then i click export, java, run-able jar file. I select the "Package required libraries into generated jar file" option.
I put a picture on this post of my package explorer inside of eclipse, in case there is a problem there.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Eclipse Package Explorer Picture]

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Where is the rest of the question?

Comment: I'm so sorry! i just updated this! I accidentally clicked save before i was done!

Comment: So you create a jar. And what happens when you run it?

Comment: The JFrame comes up, but nothing shows up inside it.

Comment: If you need more information, please do not hesitate to ask. I am not sure of the cause of the problem, and therefor may not be supplying the necessary information.

Comment: @GhostCat there are no errors or graphics, there is literally only the JFrame that comes up.

Comment: I have to go to bed for school in the morning, so i will only be able to answer questions for another 40 minutes

Comment: I still haven't found the cause of this someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to have the "package required libraries when generating JAR "selected when you exported it as a runnable .jar.